# Video in JavaFX8 doesn't replay after building a jar with Zenjava plugin

Tags: java, maven, javafx-8

I'm trying to make video play indefinite number of times and use this code:

```java
Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/media/video.mp4").toExternalForm());
MediaPlayer video = new MediaPlayer(media);
video.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
root.getChildren().add(video);
...
video.play();
```

Everything works fine while I'm running it inside Intellij, however, when I build it to executable jar with [Zenjava JavaFX Maven plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and run it, video plays only ones and then stops forever.

**Edit:**
Found out that after building MediaPlayer doesn't detect endOfMedia. By this line (prints nothing to the console, while working before building):

```
video.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> System.out.println("Ended"));
```

Any suggestions why is it happening and how to avoid it?

**Update:** I built executable jar with another library (Maven Assemble PLugin) and problem is still there. So problem is not with the builder. 
Also found out that in some cases (didn't find out precisely in which) video stops forever after pause. However, if I call

```
video.stop();
video.play();
```

it plays fine from start till the end where it again stops forever.